# Fill a circle on scroll in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a stem filling with a color and with circles for steps along the stem.

This is an example of what I'm currently aiming for: https://codepen.io/nicklassandell/pen/ztGac

This is currently what I have: https://codepen.io/TheOshika/full/xxRRVNb (the design is similar to the above code but I wrote the code from scratch)
I'm using a scrollspy script in order to trigger a filling animation in the circles. However I'm not satisfied with it because the offset for the trigger is too difficult to set for a responsive design. I'm now thinking about removing the javascript part and instead having a stem filling the circles with the scrolling, but no animation.

This is what I'm looking for, except I don't know how to make the background color in the stem fill the circles:

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  background: blueviolet;
  z-index: 3;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #4c63b6;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
}

/* stem */
.filling-stem {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #bed0f7;
}

.stem-background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #1f2933;
}

.stem-nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 100%;
}

#my-awesome-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a {
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f2933;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a .color-change {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #1f2933;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* timeline */
.timeline-container {
  position: relative;
}

.step-container {
  margin: 0 25% 0 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1500px;
}

/* footer */
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">

    <div class="filling-stem"></div>
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div class="timeline-container">
      <div class="timeline-container-inner">
        <div class="stem-background"></div>
        <div class="stem-nav">
          <ul id="my-awesome-nav">
            <li data-index="0"><a href="#step-one">
                <div class="color-change one"></div>
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="1"><a href="#step-two">
                <div class="color-change two"></div>
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="2"><a href="#step-three">
                <div class="color-change three"></div>
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="3"><a href="#step-four">
                <div class="color-change four"></div>
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="4"><a href="#step-five">
                <div class="color-change five"></div>
              </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="step-container">
          <div class="step-container-inner">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>End of the page</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Have you investigated intersectionObserver? It might help you get accurate info on when a circle needs 'filling'.

Comment: Actually, given the fixed nature of the filling (i.e. you are always filling from the mid point of the viewport in the vertical direction) you could use some divs with radial-gradient backgrounds and forget looking for scroll event at all - pure CSS/HTML.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you for your answer. Regarding intersectionOberserver I don't think I'm experienced enough to use it. My first idea to solve this was to use `window.matchMedia` and adjust the offset accordingly. As for the radial-gradient background how would it work to produce the desired design? Could you explain a little bit more about how your solution works?

Comment: I'll have a go at putting a snippet into an answer in hour or two - what I was thinking was to have some divs (or pseudo elements) which have a 'bite' out of them to make the circles - this can be done with just CSS/HTML - then as the user scrolls the background shows through - no need for sensing scrolling or any JS, but it may need more divs.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks for your answer, I'm still not sure about how it would be done so I'm very curious to see your snippet.

Comment: I have put an initial snippet in an answer - as it turned out we needed fewer rather than more HTML elements - by introducing pseudo elements on the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to get the required 'filling' effect using just CSS.

We add a pseudo before and a pseudo after element to each of the li elements. These have a radial-gradient background which has a transparent 'bite' out at the position of the circles containing the a (anchor) element. Behind the whole thing we put a fixed element which has the 'fill' color in the top half and the darker (non-filled) color in the bottom half. This is done by giving it a background image which is a linear gradient.

The inner divs (inside the anchor elements) are not now needed.

Here is a snippet to show the idea. CSS variables have been introduced to make it easier to change dimensions if required. (Note: there is redundant CSS in here which could do with tidying up.)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  --stemw: 5px; /* the width of the stem */
  --circled: 40px; /* the diameter of the circles */
  --lih: 300px; /* the height of each list item */
  --nolis: 5; /* the number of items in the list */
  
  --halfstemw: calc(var(--stemw) / 2);
  --circler: calc(var(--circled) / 2); /* the circle radius */
  --halflih: calc(var(--lih) / 2);
}

div.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1f2933 0%, #1f2933 50%, #bed0f7 50%, #bed0f7 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#my-awesome-nav li {
  position: relative;
}

#my-awesome-nav li::before, #my-awesome-nav li::after {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% + var(--circler)));
  width: calc(50vw - var(--halfstemw));
  height: var(--lih);
  top: calc(var(--halflih) * -1);
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}

#my-awesome-nav li::before {
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% + var(--halfstemw)) calc(50% + var(--circler)), transparent 0%, transparent 3%,  #4c63b6 3%, #4c63b6 100%);
}

#my-awesome-nav li::after{
  left: calc(50vw + var(--halfstemw));
  background: radial-gradient(circle at calc(var(--halfstemw) * -1) calc(50% + var(--circler)), transparent 0%, transparent 3%,  #4c63b6 3%, #4c63b6 100%);
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  background: blueviolet;
  z-index: 3;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #4c63b6;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
}

/* stem */
.filling-stem {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #bed0f7;
}

.stem-background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #1f2933;
}

.stem-nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 100%;
}

#my-awesome-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f2933;
  background-color: transparent;
}
/*
#my-awesome-nav li a .color-change {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #1f2933;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
*/
/* timeline */
.timeline-container {
  position: relative;
}

.step-container {
  margin: 0 25% 0 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1500px;
}

/* footer */
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">

    <div class="filling-stem"></div>
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div class="timeline-container">
      <div class="timeline-container-inner">
        <div class="stem-background"></div>
        <div class="stem-nav">
          <ul id="my-awesome-nav">
            <li data-index="0"><a href="#step-one">
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="1"><a href="#step-two">
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="2"><a href="#step-three">
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="3"><a href="#step-four">
              </a></li>
            <li data-index="4"><a href="#step-five">
              </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="step-container">
          <div class="step-container-inner">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>End of the page</p>
</footer>
```

Footnote: on retina screens I've occasionally seen a faint line between the pseudo elements - I think it's where the positioning calculations come at part of a CSS pixel (which on a high res screen may mean a screen pixel is 'left behind'). It's probably necessary to make the pseudo elements 1 CSS pixel higher to overlap the next one to give a continuous effect to the background.

Comment: This is a good solution to my issue, I still have to work on some parts because I noticed on chrome the render was a bit different (we can see the stem in the circles on chrome). Thank you for your time and I'll keep working on the final design on my side. In the meantime, I have started to implement a solution for the offset using `window.matchMedia`. I will continue to work on both solutions and take the more relevant one in the end.

Comment: Regarding my comment above: I fixed the bug on chrome, it was due to my own css, your solution works very well. Thanks!